# gradle tasks.withType does not find tasks defined in other file

Tags: gradle

I have two gradle files, setup.gradle and tests.gradle; each having two gradle tasks of custom type 'EMTest';

test.gradle applies the 'setup.gradle' as apply from: 'setup.gradle'

I want to configure all tasks of type EMTest; For that I added below code at end of tests.gradle

```
tasks.withType(EMTest) {
    println it.name
}
```

But this only prints the name of tasks in the tests.gradle;

When I run

```
tasks.all { 
    println it.name + " " + it.class
}
```

It however lists the tasks name defined in setup.gradle and the type as EMTest_Decorated (for all 4 types)

NOTE: I use gradle 1.11 (no control over upgrade); What is the issue here ?

### UPDATE On 09/Jun

Here is the main file :

```
apply plugin: 'java';
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply from: 'emcpsrvs_3n_setup.gradle'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = "${artifactory_contextUrl}/repo" }
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath group:"com.mycompany.myprod.mymodule", name: "TestInfraPlugin", version: "${testinfraVersion}", transitive: true
        classpath group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', name: 'jackson-mapper-asl', version:'1.9.13'
        classpath group: 'com.mycompany.myprod', name: 'common',version:'0.1'
        classpath group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', name: 'jackson-core-asl', version:'1.9.13'
        classpath group: 'com.oracle.weblogic',name: 'jettison-1.1', version: '12.1.2-0-0'
    }
}

repositories {
    /* To check if the jar is available in local maven repository */
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url = "${artifactory_contextUrl}/repo"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'TestInfraPlugin'
import com.mycompany.myprod.gradle.testinfra.tasks.EMTest;

repositories {
    maven {
        url = "${artifactory_contextUrl}/repo"
    }
}
dependencies {
   testConfig group:'com.mycompany.myprod',name:'ui-integ-tests', version: '1.+'
   testConfig group: 'com.mycompany.myprod', name: 'emaas-platform-tenant-sdk', version: '0.1+'
  }

task unitTests(type: EMTest){
}

// Three tests are disabled due to JIRA-900
task tenantMgmtUITests(type: EMTest,dependsOn: [cleanSmall_deploy_3n_block,small_deploy_3n_block]) {
    useWebdriver = true
    small_deploy_3n_block.mustRunAfter ([cleanSmall_deploy_3n_block])

    options.suiteXmlBuilder().suite('parallel': 'none','name': 'TenantManagementUI') {
        test('name': 'TenantManagementUI') {
            classes([:]) {

                'class'('name': 'com.mycompany.package.MyTest')
            }
        }
    }
}

small_deploy_3n_cleanup.mustRunAfter ([tenantMgmtUITests])
task emcpsrvs_tenant_mgmt_ui_3n(dependsOn: [tenantMgmtUITests,small_deploy_3n_cleanup])
```

Here is the 'emcpsrvs_3n_setup.gradle' which is being applied above

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = "${artifactory_contextUrl}/repo"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'com.mycompany.myprod.emdi', name: 'TestInfraPlugin', version: "${testinfraVersion}", transitive: true
    }
}

apply plugin: 'TestInfraPlugin'
repositories {
    maven {
        url = "${artifactory_contextUrl}/repo"
    }
}

import com.mycompany.myprod.gradle.testinfra.tasks.EMTest;

ext.integDeployVersion='1.1+'
dependencies {
    testConfig group: 'com.mycompany.myprod.test', name: 'smalldeployment', version: "${integDeployVersion}"
}

/* Setup EMaaS Small Deployment */
task small_deploy_3n_block(type: EMTest) {
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    onlyIf {!System.env.SMALLDEPLOY_IGNORESETUP}
    options.suiteXmlBuilder().suite('name': 'setup_3n_env') {
        test('name': 'emaas_setup_small_deploy') {
            classes([:]) {
                'class'('name': 'mycompany.sysman.test.emaas.integ.EmaasSmallDeploy3n') {
                    methods([:]) {
                        'include' ('name': 'setupEmaasSmallDeploy')
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    useWebdriver = true
    useRestAssured = true
}

/* Cleanup EMaaS Small Deployment */
task small_deploy_3n_cleanup(type: EMTest) {
    onlyIf {!System.env.SMALLDEPLOY_IGNORESETUP}
    options.suiteXmlBuilder().suite('name': 'setup_3n_env') {
        test('name': 'emaas_setup_small_deploy') {
            classes([:]) {
                'class'('name': 'mycompany.sysman.test.emaas.integ.EmaasSmallDeploy3n') {
                    methods([:]) {
                        'include' ('name': 'logCollectionAndPostCleanup')
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
   mustRunAfter ([small_deploy_3n_block])
}
```

And finally here is the snippet from TestInfraPlugin.groovy (The gradle plugin):

```
logger.debug "Configuring the EMTest task with default values."
project.afterEvaluate {
    project.ext.testClassesDir = new File(project.properties['emdi.T_WORK'] + '/testClasses')

    def testTasks = project.tasks.withType(EMTest)

    if (testTasks != null && testTasks.size() == 0) {
        logger.info "There are no tasks of type EMTest."
        return
    }

    def extractTask = project.tasks.findByPath('extractTestClasses') ?: 
           project.task('extractTestClasses', type: ExtractConfiguration) {
                configuration = project.configurations.testConfig
                to = project.testClassesDir
            }
    /* 
     * 1. Adding the 'extractTask' to all EMTest, to ensure that 'extractTask' is run before any 'EMTest'.
     * 2. For lazy evaluation of lrgConfig, we are NOT running the task here, but just adding as dependent task.
     */
    testTasks.each { task ->
        logger.debug "Adding dependsOn extractTask for task: ${task.name}"
        task.dependsOn extractTask
    }
} // end afterEvaluate
```

}

### What is `afterEvaluate{}` block doing:

It checks if there are any tasks of type `EMTest` and if there are creates a task to extract a configuration (named `testConfig`). This extract task is added as dependency on all the tasks of type `EMTest` such that the extract task run as first task before running any other task.

### What is happening

The `extractTestClasses` task is added as dependency to ONLY the two tasks `unitTests` and `tenantMgmtUITests` and thus the `small_deploy_3n_block` is getting executed before `extractTestClasses` resulting setup to fail, which in turn results test to fail.

Comment: Could you please provide an example that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 5):

When you reference tasks with no object it is implicitly using `project.tasks.`

```
tasks.withType(EMTest) {
    println it.name
}
```

That is why you'll only get tasks from your current project.

To include all projects you can use:

```
allprojects {
   tasks.withType(EMTest) { println it.name }
}
```

In this closure you are referencing `it.tasks`, where `it` loops over every individual project.

This will **not** work as expected since Gradle will probably not have loaded all of your sub-projects at this point, and not have reached every task define found during the full configuration phase. Therefore you must define the closure to run after all the projects are fully evaluated:

```
allprojects {
   afterEvaluate {
      tasks.withType(EMTest) { println it.name }
   }
}
```